# Korg Ms2000B backlighting screen

Tags: key-signatures, synthesizer, korg

I have a Korg MS2000b WHICH I HAVEN'T USE IT for than 8 years.This morning I powered it on with a 15v.It turn on.I turned it off.And after one hour I turn it on again and the screen is backlighting and no red light appears (bank check).
Why is that happening?

Comment: 15vdc is a bit harsh compared with the 9vdc it needs.

Comment: so it probably burned?

Comment: Possibly. Speak to Korg.